# N! modulo algorithm

Tags: c++, math, modulo

So , from what i have read on the internet , modulo can do this:

```
(a*b) % n = (a % n * b % n)%n;
```

Which i understand because a%n * b%n can be bigger than n , so we have to take modulo n again.But i don't get n! mod p.Algorithm from internet:

```
int result = 1;
for (int i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++)
{
   result = (result * i ) % p;
}
cout<<result;
  Let's say n = 3 , and p is 7.
When i = 1 , result = 1 % 7 ,
when i = 2 , result = (1%7 * 2) % 7 , and when i = 3 ,
result =((1%7*2) % 7 * 3) % 7.
```

I don't really see the connection between my first statement and this result.`From what i see , for n = 2 , n! % 7  should be (1 % 7 * 2 % 7 ) % 7 , not as the algorithm would do it:(1 % 7 * 2 ) % 7.`
I know the algorithm is right and i am missing something...Can anyone help me?

Comment: `(a*b) % n == (a%n * b) % n` is also true.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik can you explain me why ?

Comment: By definition of remainder, `a` is representable as `q*n + r` where `q=floor(a/n)` and `r=a%n`. Then `a*b == (q*n+r)*b == n*q*b + r*b`. The first component is clearly divisible by `n`, so `(a*b)%n == (r*b)%n == (a%n * b) %n`. QED

Comment: Mathematically there all the same. Practically, a * b might overflow your integer type and (a % n) * (b % n) might not.

Comment: @cosmin-andreiparaschiv More generally if `a=x mod n` and `b=y mod n` then `a*b = x*y mod n`. So if `a%n = x%n` and `b%n = y%n` then `(a*b)%n=(x*y)%n`. Your expressions are all variations on that same theme.

Comment: It helps to consider this modular arithmetic "as if" it is "base-n, keep only last digit". To see this yourself, choose n=10 and do the math in decimal. You'll quickly see how it works. 4! = 12, so %10 that's 2. 5! is 4! * 5, so 12*5, or 2*5 mod 10.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically they are the same but the computer has a limited number of bits to represent numbers and if you exceed that limit you will get unexpected results.

See the following example:

Imagine the maximum value that could be stored is `200` and you wanted to compute `X * Y % 100`.

Lets try some values for `X` and `Y`:

1. `X = 103 and Y = 98 ==> 3 * 98 > 296 OVERFLOW`
2. `X = 103 and Y = 103 ==> 3 * 3 > 9 OK`

In case 2, if you take the modulus of both before multiplying, you get a result below 200. But if you only take from one variable, you would have 309 % 200, but 309 would become some twisted value since the type can only represent up to 200.

In case 1, you would have to come up with another strategy (maybe a bigger type or transform your multiplication into sums) because the result of the multiplication would extrapolate the 200 limit.